# Resizing JTable columns automatically based on text size

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with some fields with long text and some with little text.

By default, this is how it looks:

[image]

Notice how the "Name" and "Title" rows are not shortened.

I would like to know two things:

1. How to manually set the width of Headers(Such as Name, Title, Surname)
2. How to automatically resize all of them depending on the text.

Here is the code:

```
    String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Title", "Surname", "ID"};
    Object[][] testData = {
            {"John", "Mr.", "Doe", "61020384U"},
    };

    nameTable = new JTable(testData, columnNames);
    nameTable.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    window.add(new JScrollPane(nameTable));
```

I have looked at the [Swing Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) but I either must have missed something or it isn't there.

Comment: question to the your point `2) How to automatically resize all of them depending on the text.` are you meaning somehow calculated max (for example String) lenght from each TableColumn and convert that to the pixels

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that by defalut is there 80pixels, but you can change that with follows, for example ...

```
TableColumnModel tcm = myTable.getColumnModel();
tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);     //Name
tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(40);    //Title
tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(400);    //Surname
tcm.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(40);    //ID
```

EDIT

to your second question is better look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Setcolumnwidthbasedoncellrenderer.htm), please there are lots of usefull examples about TableColumn

Answer (score 7):

> 2.How to automatically resize all of them depending on the text.

Check out the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/).