# Fill JLists inside GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlist, gridbaglayout, preferredsize

I have two `JLists` that should fill up equal amount of space in a `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout`. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

As the image illustrates the `JList` with most content are getting more space. Tried to give them equal space with:

```
bgConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
```

But dose not seems to work as I hoped. Any ideas how to make the two `JLists` have the same `width` independently on the content and JFrame size(and not wider then necessary)?

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GridBagTest {

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 1;
        panel.add(getList(2),c);
        panel.add(getList(10),c);

        // Show content
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a JList
     * @param strLength The length of the String in the List
     * @return A JList with a String and JScrollPane
     */
    private static JScrollPane getList(int strLength){
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();  
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);

        String str = "";
        for(int i=0; i<strLength; i++)
            str += i;

        listModel.addElement(str);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
        return pane;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

- [setPrototypeCellValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28java.lang.Object%29) for inital PreferredSize accepted by GridBagLayout and JFrame.pack();
- `JList` into `JScrollPane`,
- [JTable (with two Column ) instead of two JLists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033549/714968)